# how to use a django variable in an <a> tag's href?

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create a `list` of entries in which each entry is linked to its page like this: `wiki/entry-title`. I'm using a `for` loop to add `<li>`s to HTML. here's the code:

```
<ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li><a href="">{{ entry }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

urlpattern:

```
path('wiki/<str:title>', views.entry, name='entry')
```

what should I type in `href` to link the `<li>` to `wiki/entry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your value in url as

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <a href="/wiki/{{entry.value}}"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Its better to use [**{% url %} [Django-doc]**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tags as

```
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <a href="{% url 'your-url-name' entry.value %}"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**NOTE :** change `value` with your value accordingly. For e.g. `{{entry.value}}` or `{{entry.title}}` or `{{entry.id}}`

Answer (score 1):

There is a clear example in the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#examples)

```
<ul>
  {% for yearvar in year_list %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'news-year-archive' yearvar %}">{{ yearvar }} Archive</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In django, the template parser always handles django code first, then html/javascript. So you would insert a django variable into an anchor tag the same way you'd insert it anywhere in the template and the parser will replace it before it tries to render the html. If it's a django url, you can use the `{% %}` format as referenced in the previous answer, and if it's a url that's perhaps stored on the object, you can just use `{{ }}` (like `{{ entry.wiki_url }}`). You can also use text for some of the url and a variable for part. So if you have a wiki site that has a base url of, for instance, `https://mywiki.com` you'd write the href like:

```
<ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <a href="https://mywiki.com/{{entry.title}}"><li>{{ entry.title }}</li></a>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the only solution that was working for me was this format

```
<a href="{% url 'url_path_name' x %}"> {{ x }} </a>
```

- `x`: this is variable that we want to implement inside href attribute
- `'url_path_name'` : this is the name of the url we gave in urls.py , see :

```
path("wiki/<str:name>" , views.entry, name="url_path_name")
```

So this defined url should look like this:

```
wiki/ ? 
href="{% url 'url_path_name' x %}"
```